# Displaying 'print' output when working in Processing script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

How can I configure the development environment when writing processing scripts with PyQGIS that I can actually see print output?

For example, the following script only opens the gui for running an operation, but the print output is not visible.

[image: Basic script printing all project's map layers]

Comment: Making a Processing script a bit complicated. It's not similar to writing code in the QGIS Python Editor. It has a specific syntax. Please check these pages: (1) [Writing new Processing algorithms as Python scripts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html) (2) [Writing Python Scripts for Processing Framework (QGIS3)](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/processing_python_scripts.html).

Comment: This is Processing script editor window. When you use `print`, you see the output in Python console.

Comment: Ah, so I have to open the Python console next to the script, so that I can see the print output. Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick question: with QGIS Python editior it is meant the interactive QGIS Python console? I'm kind of confused, as my processing script works when I click the run-button, even though I don't use classes in my processsing script (as the ones created in the template script). I import my file by specifying the path to it and creating an object with OgisVectorLayer (as according to the pyqgis Cookbook) and so far it works as expected. So, do I have to use the script template, or is it just a suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I mean the interactive QGIS Python console. Since the Processing Script Editor is a Python editor, when you run the script it is run like a Python script. But this editor is customized for coding Processing scripts. The script you mentioned is not added to the processing toolbox. If you stick to the syntax rules, your code will be added to the Processing Toolbox ([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdYdY.png)).